# Complex number as result of an integral

Tags: numerics

I am a beginner with mathematica and I am trying to evaluate the next integral but i got a complex number as a result.

Am i doing something wrong or is this the result of the integral?

$$
\int_0^{0.8}\cos^2(\frac{\pi z}{1.6})dz (\int_z^{\infty}\frac{e^{-3.367u}}{u^2}du -3z^2\int_z^{\infty}\frac{e^{-3.367u}}{u^4}du)
$$

Thank you for any help

This is the code:

```
int1 = Assuming[z >= 0,Integrate[Exp[-3367*u/1000 ]/u^2, {u, z, Infinity}]]
int2 = Assuming[z >= 0,Integrate[Exp[-3367*u/1000 ]/u^4, {u, z, Infinity}]]
Integrate[(Cos[Pi z/(16/10)]^2)*(int1 - 3*(z^2)*int2), {z, 0, 8/10},PrincipalValue -> True]
```

Comment: I think you should post your code

Comment: ok! i have already posted the code

Comment: It is worth investigating, that your possibly complex part comes from the `I(ExpIntegralEi[-(3367/1250) - I π] - ExpIntegralEi[-(3367/1250) + I π])` subexpression. When I see this correct, then you can replace the `ExpIntegralEi` expressions with `Gamma[0, z]` and by taking into account that your z are complex conjugates, it might be possible to show analytically that the expression is indeed real.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i still dont understand why mathematica got this subexpression with complex numbers if the initial expression only contains real numbers? Because at the beginning the function exponential integral dépends on real numbers

Answer (score 1):

If you simplify the last expression, you get

```
Integrate[(Cos[Pi z/(16/10)]^2)*(int1 - 3*(z^2)*int2), {z, 0,8/10},PrincipalValue -> True]
zw=FullSimplify[%, z > 0]
Chop[zw //N]
(* -0.606023 *)
```

which is real!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! one question, what is the function 'chop' for?  (sorry I am a beginner with mathematica)

Comment: Chop[expr]
replaces approximate real numbers in expr that are close to zero by the exact integer 0.